# sqlite IN check set coverage

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can SQLite check set coverage using the `IN` operator?

ie
`(SELECT n from nums where n < 4) IN (1,2,3,4)`
(where nums is the set of whole numbers) would return true

I have searched the documents but can only find documents where they are only using a single value on the left of `IN`.
Tests have returned that it can, but I need to confirm this is a valid use case and not a side effect like the ability for SQLite to return aggregate queries without proper `GROUP BY` statements.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it can"? The expression you've shown is not valid in any version of SQLite.

Comment: **NO**. Only a *single value* is checked to be in a set. I.e.: `2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` would return true.

Comment: @CL if you run a sub query like this where num is a table of whole numbers (select n from num where n < 3) IN ( 1,2,3,4) it will return true. But if you run (select n from num where n < 4) IN ( 1,2,4) it will return false which is the expected behaviour. Apologies, i miss typed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) says:

> The IN and NOT IN operators take a single scalar operand on the left

So if you use a subquery on the left side, it is treated as a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq), which does not behave as you want it to:

> The result of the expression is the value of the only column in the first row returned by the SELECT statement. If the SELECT yields more than one result row, all rows after the first are ignored.

To check for set coverage, you have to check if there is any element in the left set that is not in the right set:

```
WITH a(n) AS (
  SELECT n
  FROM nums
  WHERE n < 4
),
b(n) AS (
  VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
)
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM b
                  WHERE b.n = a.n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says no.

The IN and NOT IN operators take a **single scalar** operand on the left and a vector operand on the right formed by an explicit list of zero or more scalars or by a single subquery.

*Emphasis mine*

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op